# Ant compile with javac Main Class not found

Tags: java, ant, javafx

I already searched here for a solution but none worked for me:
I have a build script written in Ant:

```
<project name="Musifx" basedir="." default="main">
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>

<property name="build.dir" value="out"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="properties.file" value="${src.dir}/qs_musifx.properties"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>
<property name="main-class" value="quakk.musifx.main.Main"/>

<target name="clean">
  <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
  <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
  <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpath="${lib.dir}/Logger.jar" includes="${lib.dir}/*.jar"/>
  <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
  </copy>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
  <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
  <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
    </manifest>
  </jar>
</target>
<target name="run" depends="jar">
  <java classname="${main-class}" fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
</project>
```

My folder structure is ./quakk/musifx/main/ and my package is quakk.musifx.main

As I said, I tried various solutions posted here but every time I try to run my "main" target in Ant I get the following Error

```
Fehler: Hauptklasse quakk.musifx.main.Main konnte nicht gefunden oder geladen werden
```

Which translates roughly to Mainclass: quakk.musifx.main.Main could not be found or loaded.

I also tried to change the class path or the name of the Mainclass and tried to change my main-class property to simply "Main" or "quakk.musifx.main"
or to include the class path in the compile target but nothing worked for me.

By the way I am using JDK 8 and this is a JavaFX Application

Edit: Output of jar tvf Musifx.jar

```
0 Thu Jul 30 00:00:00 CEST 2015 META-INF/
139 Wed Jul 29 23:59:58 CEST 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
0 Wed Jul 29 23:59:58 CEST 2015 quakk/
0 Wed Jul 29 23:59:58 CEST 2015 quakk/musifx/
0 Wed Jul 29 23:59:58 CEST 2015 quakk/musifx/main/
425 Wed Jul 29 23:59:58 CEST 2015 qs_musifx.properties
1866 Wed Jul 29 23:59:58 CEST 2015 quakk/musifx/main/main.fxml
1076 Wed Jul 29 23:59:58 CEST 2015 quakk/musifx/main/styles.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to change my targets for `compile` and `jar`:

```
<target name="compile">
<mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
<javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="${lib.dir}/Logger.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</javac>
<copy todir="${classes.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
</copy>
</target>
```

and the `jar` target

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
<mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>

<jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="Logger.jar" />
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
</target>
```

Now it works and compiles to my jar file and the Application works as it should

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to run your main class without providing a classpath.

I would suggest changing to:

```
<target name="run" depends="jar">
  <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>
```

which would run the JAR you've just built (and as it does have a `Main-Class` in its manifest will run that.

Comment: You mean in the jar Target?
That I replace the whole jar Target with this?

Comment: it says that it must run with fork="true", so I changed and the same error appears

Comment: Does an `out/classes/quakk/musifx/main/Main.class` file exist after you've run ant?

Comment: Yes, every file needed is present in the `out/` folder

Comment: and how about in the JAR file?  If you do a `jar tvf Musifx.jar`?

Comment: I added an edit to my question and I see that the class files are not in my jar-file

Comment: That would be the reason as to why it can't load the class.  As to why the class files are not in there I'm a bit stumped I'm afraid as the jar task looks right to me...  It might be worth running this with `ant -v` to switch verbose mode to see why it is not adding the class files to the JAR.